# ./src/productsection.js Attempted import error: 'bindActionCreaters' is not exported from 'redux'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is the error I am getting, kindly help. I look up through the internet and can't find anything

```
./src/productsection.js Attempted import error: 'bindActionCreaters' is not exported from 'redux'.

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreaters } from 'redux';

function Products({users}) {
  function displayitem(){
    return users.map((user) => {
      return (
        <button onClick={()=>users.selectUser(user)}>Add to cart </button>
     </div>
      );
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { displayitem() }
    </div>
  );
}

function mapStatetoProps(state){
  return {
    users: state.users ,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreaters({ selectUser: selectUser }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

Comment: Voting to close, issue caused by typo. `bindActionCreaters` -> `bindActionCreators`.

Answer (score 0):

rename bindActionCreaters to bindActionCreators